# uncaught reference error jquery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error:

```
uncaught reference error jquery is not defined
```

I receive the error when doing inspect element in Google Chrome. 
I don't understand JavaScript and this was done by someone else.

Please note:
I clearly didn't know anything about JS before and the community, although very brutally, made that clear. Sorry about the simplistic post but that wasn't my intention.
This is the script:

```
function showwaitpagedummy() {
  var strSelectedRegion = $('country')[$('country').selectedIndex].text;
  var strSelectedDes = $('destair')[$('destair').selectedIndex].text;
  var strSelectedFromDes = $('depair')[$('depair').selectedIndex].text;
  var strSelectedNights = $('nights')[$('nights').selectedIndex].text;


  if (strSelectedRegion == 'Any Region') {
    $("dvError").update("You must choose a region");
    return false;
  } else if (strSelectedDes == 'Any Destination') {
    $("dvError").update("You must choose a destination");
    return false;
  } else if (strSelectedFromDes == 'Any Airport') {
    $("dvError").update("You must choose a depature airport");
    return false;
  } else if (strSelectedNights == 'Any night') {
    $("dvError").update("You must choose nights");
    return false;
  }


  $('frmFlightAccom').submit();
  $('waitpagedummy').show();
}
```

Comment: But then include jQuery on your site...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add a reference to jQuery in your html.

Add this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

You should also include

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Since you use prototype which uses the `$`. All jQuery code must start with `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: It looks like OP should use jQuery noConflict too as `$` is already defined. That's said, i'm too lazy to debug OP's website ;) EDIT: i see, website includes prototype.js

Comment: OP still needs to include jQuery in some way ;)

Comment: Why is using `$(document)` any better than using `jQuery(document)`? Especially in the case where multiple libraries are loaded.

Comment: @Zirak: Is it better now?

Comment: missing a closing tag here: should be => <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: That fixed the issue

Comment: Correct! I have learned this at past but forgotten now

Answer (score 3):

**included jQuery in head & clear cache its working grt**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```